# jQuery plugin with unforseen options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to create a jQuery plugin that takes some interesting options as parameters. Here is what the call would look like ideally.

```
$.bindMultiple('click', {
    'selector1': function1,
    'selector2': function2
});
```

The selectors are normal jQuery selectors (e.g., input[type=checkbox]) and the functions are functions in the javascript that will be called on the bound event (click in this instance is the event that the programmer wants to bind to all of these elements).

What I am wondering is how to access all of the options that are sent in. This is what I have so far:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.bindMultiple = function(bindEvent, options) {           

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

**EDIT**: Thanks to adeneo I found out that I needed to change $.fn.bindMultiple... to $.bindMultiple...

Comment: Why would you need a plugin for that ?

Comment: @adeneo actually I can imagine he makes some super-complex animation and wants to save code.

Comment: @MightyPork Yes, that is why I want to make this plugin. Another reason is that I want to learn how to make plugins and this is applicable to me.

Comment: @adeneo It seems that making this plugin would be trite for you. Since it would be so easy for you, can you show me how I would get all of the options sent in?

Comment: Look @ my answer, then ;)

Comment: Getting the options isn't a problem, but the concept is flawed. When building plugins on `$.fn` you call the method on a collection, like so `$('elements').bindMultiple(options)`, but with what you're doing it looks like you're really just trying to add a property to `jQuery` as you are calling your plugin as `$.bindMultiple`, and it's really just a regular function, so I don't get what it is you're trying to do ?

Comment: @adeneo you are right. I had to take out the ".fn" portion and then MightyPork's answer worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't make some stupid typo, this will work:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.bindMultiple = function(bindEvent, options) {        

        $.each(options, function(selector, func){
            $(selector).on(bindEvent, func);
        });
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: Wow! That did it! I did have to make a change so that I can call the function like this: $.bindMultiple(). I took out the fn. adeneo was right.

Comment: How does jQuery know that the two arguments that you passed into function(selector, func) are the options that were sent into the plugin call?

Comment: that is in fact jQuery's FOREACH: $.each(array, function(key, value){}); I just renamed the arguments to make it easier to read.

Comment: Gotcha. This is awesome. Thank you, MightyPork.

Comment: Now the question is, how do I pass parameter into the functions that are called? Because when I was calling them the regular way I had access to $(this)->(The element) within the function and now I don't.

Comment: well, they get the event object as argument. You can use event.target, like described here: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/  Then you can take data from the element or whatever you wanted to do with it.